# Can't install WTP (Web Tools Platform) in Eclipse - something about missing dependencies...?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to install the WTP plug-in for Eclipse Luna (4.4.0), but I'm having some difficulties.
When I choose this:
 [image]

and click Next, it says that it cannot perform the operation, and it shows me this:
[image]

When I choose "Show original error...", I get the following:
[image]

Why am I getting this error and how can I finally install the WTP?

Comment: WTP 3.6 is the release for Luna

Comment: and how can I get it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F . Basically you should be using the Luna site itself.

Comment: Thank you!!! I used the repository http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/luna/ to download WTP 3.6