# Not able to create Dynamic web project in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I have installed Eclipse Luna for windows 64 bit. But I am not able to create a new Dynamic Web Project. I also installed **Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development** , but still it shows only Static Web Project inside Web projects.

Is there anything else to be installed ?

Comment: What type of error you getting. Can you please provide screen short.

Comment: Check your current perspective, try changing it to javaEE

Comment: Hi Jani.. No.. not any error.. but the option is not available under File > New > Others > Web >

Comment: @ares Not even in javaEE.

Comment: Have you downloaded the java EE version of Luna?

Comment: @ares I have downloaded Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development which includes Java EE.. I changed perspective to Java EE but still not getting Dynamic Web Project.

Comment: Download the EE version afresh. Maybe your installation isn't proper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need the Web Tools Platform package for this
add it to your eclipse through Help > install new software.

Then add the software repository site location for WTP for your version of eclipse.

```
http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the accepted answer is not the recommended solution.  In Luna you should install Web Tools Platform via the Luna download site, not the WTC download site.

Here are the instructions:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F

Here is what happens if you use WTP site:
[Can't install WTP (Web Tools Platform) in Eclipse - something about missing dependencies...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126669/cant-install-wtp-web-tools-platform-in-eclipse-something-about-missing-depe)

Yes, I see that the asker says he has done this, so I guess the accepted answer worked for him, but I think people should try this recommended method first.

Answer (score -1):

You need to go to  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo or luna or whatever version of eclipse you are using and select Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development.